# Transfering DateInfo Bootstrap to JavaScript Variable and then PHP Variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I implemented a Bootstrap Calendar and I tried following:

```
// First try
function post() {
  var neueDaten = $(".form-control").val();
}
console.log(neueDaten);

// Second try
$('input.form-control').val();
```

When I use this on the console of the browser I get the date which the user picked but I cant transfer it to a variable

```
<input type='text' class="form-control"/>class="form-control"/>
```

Comment: on the first try the variable above is clearly out of scope, your second try doesn't do anything as it stands, you just accessed the value but not used in any way

Comment: can u show me a example how to do that?

Comment: Just move the `console.log()` inside the `post()` function - assuming the `post()` function is called from somewhere, and there's no errors in the console

Comment: thx i found the problem: i had two datepickers startdate and enddatem the problem was both had the same class i changed it to different ids and it startet working thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of scope means that the variable neueDaten "is visible" inside function post() (local scope) but not outside of it (global scope) : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

For the first try you could :

```
// First try
function post() {
  var neueDaten = $(".form-control").val();
  console.log(neueDaten);
}
```

For the second try you need to do something of the input value like :

```
// Second try
console.log($('input.form-control').val());
```